# Why do up and down arrow commands not work in the Python command line interpreter?

Tags: python, linux, cpython

I am using a VT100 terminal emulator on Linux. In bash, up and down arrows scroll through the last commands executed; they work as expected.

Previous (up arrow) and next (down arrow) commands are not interpreted in the Python command line interpreter. What kind of key mappings do I need to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: Technically, up-arrow and down-arrow are interpreted just fine; the issue is that, as IDLE uses a textbox/textfield-type window to display its data, pressing "up" and "down" just moves the cursor up or down in the window. Don't treat IDLE like a terminal window.

Comment: @JAB Noted, but how do I treat it to get the last command?

Comment: I've removed IDLE from the title and post, because it is not clear to me there is another term for Python command line interpreter.

Comment: In that case, the command-line interpreter normally does support the usage of arrow keys for command completion, so check whatever customization you've performed if any to make sure you aren't overriding such functionality somehow.

Comment: @JAB but that's what I'm asking. What kind of terminal does the command line interpreter expect?

Comment: you should have something like "python (command line)" which will open a terminal with a python interactive session.  and I think the term you're looking for is "python shell"

Comment: What Python implementation are you using? CPython, the default/most common one, does use a Unix-style interface, but other implementations may not. http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#interface-options

Comment: I'm on Linux using default Python 2.7 that I downloaded from the official Python site, so it must be CPython.

Comment: @xhainingx "shell" isn't really an appropriate term for the Python interpreter.

Comment: When you Python in a terminal outside of the VT100 emulator, can you use the up- and down- arrows to cycle through commands?

Comment: @JAB python shell is what IDLE calls an interactive session

Comment: @xhainingx: In that situation, I'd say that the IDLE window is acting as a shell for the interpreter. ...Wikipedia does describe the Python interpreter's interactive mode as being a "shell mode", however, so I guess you are right after all. Oh well.

Comment: @JAB yeah it's probably not the most accurate term but because of IDLE (I assume), it has become a fairly common one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, assuming you have the GNU Readline library. (This does mean I was partially wrong about the base implementation using a Unix-style interface, as it only does that when GNU Readline [or a port, I guess] isn't available.)

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interactive.html#history-substitution

> History substitution works as follows. All non-empty input lines issued are saved in a history buffer, and when a new prompt is given you are positioned on a new line at the bottom of this buffer. `C-P` moves one line up (back) in the history buffer, `C-N` moves one down. Any line in the history buffer can be edited; an asterisk appears in front of the prompt to mark a line as modified. Pressing the Return key passes the current line to the interpreter. `C-R` starts an incremental reverse search; `C-S` starts a forward search.

Answer (score 8):

By default, the keymappings are:

- older: <kbd>alt-p</kbd>
- more recent: <kbd>alt-n</kbd>

You can change it in `Options -> Configure IDLE -> Keys -> "history-previous"` and `"history-next"` respectively.

Comment: I've edited the original question to indicate this is the command line version of IDLE. How can I set options via the command line? Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember if this is true for terminal input or not, but in IDLE you can also type the first part of a previous statement from further back before pressing Alt+N in order to retrieve that earlier statement without going through the ones in between.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Last I checked, IDLE is a (fairly basic) IDE that utilizes Python's `tkinter` module in order to display a Tk/TCL-based GUI. I've never heard of there being a command-line version of it (though you can start it from a terminal, of course).

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I'm wondering about the same thing? How do you start IDLE in the terminal?

Comment: @JonClements Indeed, though that only really makes a difference when the text you type first matches with multiple previous commands, in which case an initial press of alt+p will retrieve the newest and of alt+n will retrieve the oldest (because the history commands wrap around).

Comment: Perhaps the tag is wrong, but IDLE is the Python command line that ships with Python. I'm not referring to a GUI IDE. If IDLE is called something else, I'll gladly edit the original question to use the correct term.

Comment: Hang on - do you mean you just type "python" in the terminal window and work from that?

Comment: @JonClements Yes. I have a VT100 emulated window, and type Python.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: You are using the Python interpreter in a terminal. That is not the same as IDLE, and the two should not be confused with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the `readline` package:

```
pip install readline
```